# How to bypass Jekyll Build by GitHub and Deploy _site folder directly?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

How can I `bypass jekyll compilation at GitHub` and push _site folder (after local compilation) and host there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want github page to process you site with Jekyll, you can add an empty `.nojekyll` file at the root of your generated code. See [mojombo post](https://github.com/blog/572-bypassing-jekyll-on-github-pages).

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special to do; just use your _site folder as the content for you github pages.

You can't bypass the compilation step, but it will not modify your content.

Just try and run **jekyll serve** locally in your _site folder to make sure.

EDIT: @David Jacquel's answer is more accurate